# Parsing a nested aggregation query response

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

This is the result of a nested ES aggregation query. I need to parse this response and convert it to a new JSON format. From the following JSON, the only fields i'm interested are the values key_as_a_string and value of apples and oranges for each key.

```
"aggregations": {
    "Inner_aggregation": {
        "doc_count": 366,
        "Hours_aggregation": {
            "doc_count": 366,
            "by_day": {
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key_as_string": "2016-01-11",
                        "key": 1452556800000,
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "Apples": {
                            "value": 5
                        },
                        "Oranges": {
                            "value": 3
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key_as_string": "2016-01-12",
                        "key": 1452556800000,
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "Apples": {
                            "value": 43
                        },
                        "Oranges": {
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    },
                    .........,
                    .........
                ]
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I can parse it using Jackson objectmapper or using sr.getAggregations().get("histogram_name") method and then iterating over the collections. Wanted to know if there's an easy way out there.

**Required JSON format**

```
{
    "Results": [{
        "key_as_string": "2016-01-11",
        "Apple_to_Orange_Ratio": 0.112
    }, {
        "key_as_string": "2016-01-12",
        "Apple_to_Orange_Ratio": 0.12
    }]
}
```

Ratio will be found by simple division of apple and orange count.

Comment: no, it is there rest interface response coming from the cluster, you cannot modify the response format.That's the  whole point of rest.You may need a translator between your cluster and client to translate the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your Java representation is quite different to a complex nested structure it can be unhelpful to map the json directly to Java classes. You could deal with this kind of data dynamically.

Here's a way to deal with such data using Java 8 & the library [Dynamics](https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics).

We parse the json to a map/list structure, and wrap this as a Dynamic instance

```
Map jsonMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(exampleJson, Map.class);
Dynamic jsonData = Dynamic.from(jsonMap);
```

This gives us a null-safe & fluent way to deal with this nested structure. In this case we're interested in the buckets, and it would be nice to get at these easily.

```
List<MyResult> results = jsonData
    .dget("aggregations.Inner_aggregation.Hours_aggregation.by_day.buckets")
    .children()
    .map(bucket -> new MyResult(bucket))
    .collect(toList());
```

Now our class MyResult can deal with the bucket data which is also a Dynamic instance.

```
public class MyResult {
    private final Dynamic bucket;

    public Result(Dynamic bucket) {
        this.bucket = bucket;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return bucket.get("key_as_string").asString();
    }

    public double getAppleToOrangeRatio() {
        double apples = bucket.dget("Apples.value").convert().intoDouble();
        double oranges = bucket.dget("Oranges.value").convert().intoDouble();
        return oranges / apples;
    }
}
```

And we can access the ratios.

```
double appleToOrangeRatio = results.get(0).getAppleToOrangeRatio();
// 0.6
```

See https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics for source, documentation and examples.